# C++ compile issue with c++11

Tags: c++, macos, time, compilation

I am trying to compile a few C++ files from a make file. I keep on getting this error:

```
<i> no member named 'to_time_t' in
      'std::__1::chrono::steady_clock'; did you mean
      'std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t'? 
    time_t tnow = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::to_time_t(now);

</i>
```

Then after some research I found out that this is because I'm not using c++ 11. I'm on a MAC OS X 10.10.2. So I installed brew and then installed gcc and g++ 4.9 using brew. However, I still get the same error. Any suggestions? This code runs on a linux machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, I did make sure that version 4.9 of g++ is being used by changing the path and adding symlinks etc.

Comment: Symlinks? That sounds very dubious! Did you set the c++11 compile mode by adding the compiler flag: `-std=c++11`?

Comment: yes I have that in the make file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`to_time_t` is a member of `system_clock`, but not (necessarily) of `steady_clock` or `high_resolution_clock`. You are using `high_resolution_clock`, which on your system, going by the error message, appears to be an alias of `steady_clock`, not of `system_clock`. If the code is working for you on another platform, it could be that on that platform, `high_resolution_clock` is an alias for `system_clock`, but you can't rely on this always being the case.

The solution is to just use `system_clock`, if you wan't a `time_t` from it. `system_clock` should be at least as high resolution as `time_t`, so using a potentially higher resolution clock here doesn't buy you anything. Or just use the `std::time` function in the first place, if you simply want the current time.

Comment: I don't think this is the solution to it, because I was able to run this on linux

Comment: @hadis: And I explained why that may be the case. Did you actually read my whole answer? Did you even look at the documentation for `high_resolution_clock`?

Comment: sorry I missed that! I will try your solution